# Template method with number of arguments fixed for instantiation but variable by template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to define a function for template class with an integer template parameter so that the number of function arguments depends on the template parameter. Here's an example:

```
template< class Coord, int dim >
class Point {
    Coord mCoords[ dim ];
public:
    void Set( /* I want exactly dim Coord arguments here. */ );
};
```

I'd like this code to compile:

```
Point<double,2> pt2d;
pt2d.Set( 25, 32 );
Point<double,3> pt3d;
pt3d.Set( 25, 32, 100 );
```

and this code to fail:

```
Point<double,2> pt2d;
pt2d.Set( 25, 32, 100 );  // Too many arguments
Point<double,3> pt3d;
pt3d.Set( 25, 32 );       // Too few arguments
```

Now, I can manually specialize `Point` in smaller dimensions to have unrelated `Set` functions, but I find the practice of essentially repeating the same code un-C++-ish. Furthermore, I shouldn't have to specialize for every possible value of the int template parameter.

Is it possible to implement `Point<Coord,dim>::Set()` function that would take exactly `dim` arguments of type `Coord` without writing specialization code for each value of `dim`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the trick that Boost.Hana uses for `getNth`:

```
template <typename Coord, int dim, typename = std::make_index_sequence<dim>>
struct Point;

template <typename Coord, int dim, size_t... Ignore>
struct Point<Coord, dim, std::index_sequence<Ignore...>>
{
    void Set(decltype(Ignore, Coord{})... args)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

---

A longer version that hides the `Ignore` ugliness a little bit (and works for non-default-constructible `Coord`s... ) would be to add some metaprogramming boilerplate:

```
template <typename... > struct typelist { };

template <int N, typename T, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
struct repeat;

template <int N, typename T>
using repeat_t = typename repeat<N, T>::type;

template <int N, typename T, size_t... Idx>
struct repeat<N, T, std::index_sequence<Idx...>>
{
    template <size_t >
    struct makeT { using type = T; };

    using type = typelist<typename makeT<Idx>::type...>;
};
```

And then specialize on `repeat_t` instead. And hide this in a namespace so a user can't mess it up:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename Coord, int dim, typename = repeat_t<dim, Coord>>
    struct Point;

    template <typename Coord, int dim, typename... dimCoords>
    struct Point<Coord, dim, typelist<dimCoords...>>
    {
        void Set(dimCoords... args)
        {

        }
    };
}

template <typename Coord, int dim>
using Point = details::Point<Coord, dim>;
```

Comment: can `ints` be deduced from an `index_sequence` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes. But changed it to `size_t` nevertheless.